# Pyhton - trying to create a function that recives a positive number and checking if the number can be created from list numbers (in order)

Tags: python

so for example i have this list: [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0]
i want to check if some integer number can be created from this list by the order of the list.
for example the integer 12358 will print TRUE but the integer 315782 will print False.

i got stuck, thats what i did but i just dont know how to continue

```
    lst = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0]
    lst_lenght = len(lst)
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    index = 0
    max_index = 0
    flag = True
    while (flag == True):
        num = int(input('\nEnter Positive integer (0 to stop):'))
        num1 = num
        num2 = num
        if (num <= 0):
            print('Finish')
            flag = False
        else:
            for i in range (lst_lenght):
```

i just dont know how to continue, i've tried to get the last digit every time and to test if the index is higher then the next digits index (num % 10 , num // 10) but i struggle

Answer (score 2):

I would convert everything to a string and then use some built-in methods:

```
def check(lst, n):
    lst = ''.join(map(str, lst))
    n = str(n)
    pos = 0
    for ch in lst:
        if pos < len(n) and ch == n[pos]:
            pos += 1
    return pos == len(n)
```

Another very smart option using iterators:

```
def check(lst, n):
    lst = ''.join(map(str, lst))
    n = str(n)
    it = iter(lst)
    return all(x in it for x in n)
```

Examples:

```
>>> check([1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0], 12358)
True
>>> check([1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0], 315782)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the integer to a string, then to a list. Then for each element in the new list, check if it is in the number list. If it is, remove the element from both lists, removing just the element in the input number, and removing the element and every element before it on the list. Repeat for every element in the list. If the length of the input string at the end is 0, then you can construct the list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about taking your input value (num), and converting it into a list of digits? For example, making the number '123' into an array, [1,2,3]. Then check the first member of the array, 1, to see if its in your list '1st'? If it isn't, you fail. If it is, you take note of where in the list '1st' the number one is found, and then search from that index number, in '1st' to the end of '1st' for the second digit. And repeat? If you get to the end of '1st', before you get to the end of the [1,2,3] array, you fail. If you get to the end of the [1,2,3] array before (or equal to) when you arrive at the end of the '1st' array.. you succeed!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you.

```py
lst = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0]
def check(num):
    try:
        letter_index = [lst.index(int(a)) for a in str(num)]
    except ValueError: # if value not in list return False
        return False
    result = False
    greater = letter_index[0]
    for i in letter_index:
        if i>=greater:
            lesser= i
            result =True
        else:
            return False
    return result


num = int(input('\nEnter Positive integer (0 to stop):'))
if check(num):
    print('True')
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list into string then find substring in that string like that:

```py
lst = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0]
list_as_string = ''.join(str(e) for e in lst)
lst_lenght = len(lst)
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
index = 0
max_index = 0
flag = True
while (flag == True):
    num = int(input('\nEnter Positive integer (0 to stop):'))
    num1 = num
    num2 = num
    if (num <= 0):
        print('Finish')
        flag = False
    else:
        checking_number = input(f"Enter {lst_lenght} number: ")
        if len(checking_number) == lst_lenght:
            if checking_number in list_as_string:
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)
        else:
            print(f"Wrong length: Please! Enter {lst_lenght} number: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options (besides the already great answers):

---

Compare lists:

You convert your string number to a list and then check if it's in your starting list of numbers. As they are found, you pop the value from the starting list into a new list. Then check your new list at the end to see if it matches your input string:

```
yourlist = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0] 
yournumber = '12358'

outlist = []
for num in list(yournumber):  
    print(num)
    if int(num) in yourlist: 
       outlist.append(str(yourlist.pop(yourlist.index(int(num)))))

print("".join(outlist) == yournumber)

>>>True
```

You may recognize the pattern (`for: if: somelist.append()`) that can be converted to list comprehension to shorten your code:

```
yourlist = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0] 
yournumber = '12358'
outlist = [str(yourlist.pop(yourlist.index(int(x)))) for x in list(yournumber) if int(x) in yourlist]
print("".join(outlist) == yournumber)

>>>True
```

---

Use Regex:

Another option here is to use regex. You can split your input string into a list, and then join it back together using `.*` as a delimiter. Then perform a regex match:

```
import re

yourlist = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,8,0] 
yournumber = '12358'

#turn `yournumber` into "1.*2.*3.*5.*8" regex string
rex=".*".join(list(yournumber))

#join your starting list into a string and test it with the regex:
print(bool(re.match(rex, "".join(map(str, yourlist)))))

>>>True
```

Note that if your list elements are more than a single digit or character this can fail:

```
yourlist = [10, 23, 5, 8]
yournumber = '12358'
```

This will say "True" even though "10" isn't in the `yournumber` variable.